# Average fluid temperature in a pipe

Tags: thermodynamics

[image]
[image]

In the context of a research project, we are trying to simulate heat flux being transferred from the water in a pipe over its length. I managed to simulate the process by dividing it up into discrete steps, but I figure there might be a way to mathematically determine the average temperature of the pipe $\not\!\circ \; T_{p}$. Assuming the surrounding temperature $T_{amb}$ is constant, I could then simply calculate the heat flux with

$$\dot Q = \alpha \cdot A \cdot (\not\!\circ \; T_{p}-T_{amb})$$

But I'm not really sure how to do it. Is it even possible?

Comment: It is definitely possible.  Did you think that engineers build chemical plants where millions of $ are at stake without knowing how to confidently design heat transfer equipment?  See Transport Phenomena by Bird, et al, Chapter 14,   Interphase Transport in non-Isothermal Systems.

Comment: Consider using log mean temperature difference (LMTD) to calculate your average.